# Sample data in expression Blend while in design mode and live data when running the application

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, blend

I have a service that returns an observable collection of persons that will be used to display the person name in a list box in my Silverlight application.

While designing the list box, the designer used sample data. However, when the xaml reaches the developer working on the view model and the service that returns an observable collection of persons to be displayed, there are some changes that need to be done.. like remove all bindings to the sample data, plug in the observable collection persons properties.

So my questions are:-

1. Is there a way to do this in a way where in design mode it shows the sample data and when it runs it shows the service data?
2. Is there a way for it to return service data while in design mode itself?
3. Does the designer using Expression Blend need to know what properties of the observable collection {persons} will be bound to the list box?

I would want to do this in an MVVM friendly manner {without using MVVM Light toolkit}.

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loads of good examples out there:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avip/archive/2010/12/06/the-simplest-way-to-do-design-time-viewmodels-with-mvvm-and-blend.aspx

http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/ddesigninstance-ddesigndata-in-visual-studio-2010-beta2/

It's very simple. Lots of other resources on google if you need them

**Edit based on comment**

*2. Is there a way for it to return service data while in design mode itself?*

Possibly but I've not seen it. In my mind you probably wouldn't want to do this for many reasons.

- You may get a delay before your data
  shows up which could get quite
  frustrating if you need to make a lot
  of small changes.
- You have a reliance on services being
  available which is going to make you
  even more unproductive if they ever
  go down.
- You or a designer doesn't have any
  control over changing what is
  displayed on an ad-hoc basis. At
  least using the sample data system
  you can change values to test
  different scenarios without having to
  get services data changed.

*3. Does the designer using Expression Blend need to know what properties of the observable collection {persons} will be bound to the list box?*

The designer/developer workflow is a tricky one. Obviously each project will be different, but having just finished a design heavy wpf project I can tell you that our designers want as little to do with Blend as possible.

The workflow that has worked for us, is for the developers (we have a front end team that work at the view/viewmodel level and backend team that build up the model and service layer) to build up the views as best they can. That means building the layout, composing the controls, adding most of the design and hooking up the bindings.  We then had a designer who had experience in using Blend (there aren't many) delve in and tweak the designs to get them exactly as they wanted.

This way they had very little to do with the main brunt of the work and we could keep clean and organised views (something few designers would have the experience to do). The designers didn't really have to know anything about domain objects.  It all worked very well once we'd worked out how it was going to work.  Having the designers build up the views themselves would have been a nightmare in my opinion... and not something they'd have enjoyed either.

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying Google before this without much luck... I may be not using the right keywords probably. Is there anything to help me with question number 2 and 3 above?

Comment: Thanks James. Your opinion was helpful.